# package index lost converting to unary stack

Tags: ros, camera1394, documentation, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am converting [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) to a unary stack for Fuerte. The indexer has seen this change, and `camera1394` is no longer included as a [camera_drivers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers) package. (It is now a dependency, instead.)

I changed the package header for `camera1394` to `<<StackHeader(camera1394)>>`, but that header information is not displayed in the wiki. Instead it says: "Cannot load information on camera1394, which means that it is not yet in our index. Please see this page for information on how to submit your repository to our index."

The source trunk moved from:

- `https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/camera_drivers/trunk/camera1394`

to:

- `https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/camera1394/trunk`

Since both are contained in `ros-pkg/stacks`, I expected the new `camera1394` stack to be indexed automatically. How can I make that happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11787/package-index-lost-converting-to-unary-stack/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We don't index all of ros-pkg/stacks for that contains all the branches as well as trunks.  We only index specific subdirectories.  We'll need update the indexer to add camera1394 explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-03**:
I should have realized that. Thanks!